# Cannot load OCI shared library (oci.dll) in ocilib

Tags: c, oracle11g, codeblocks, ocilib

I have a probem with runnig ocilib_demo project in codeblocks I am getting this error:

Cannot load OCI shared library (oci.dll)

Operating system: Windows 10

build log:

```
mingw32-gcc.exe -Wall -O2 -DOCI_API=__stdcall -DOCI_CHARSET_ANSI -
IC:\Users\aisni\Desktop -c C:\ocilib\demo\ocilib_demo.c -o "MinGW\Release - 
ANSI\demo\ocilib_demo.o"
mingw32-g++.exe  -o "MinGW\Release - ANSI\ocilib_demo.exe" "MinGW\Release - 
ANSI\demo\ocilib_demo.o"  -s  ..\..\lib32\libociliba.a
Output file is MinGW\Release - ANSI\ocilib_demo.exe with size 358.50 KB
Process terminated with status 0 (0 minute(s), 11 second(s))
0 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 11 second(s))
```

Answer (score 1):

oci.dll is not found either in executable directory, system folders,  folder listed in PATH environment variable nor in the folder optionally passed to OCI_Initialize().

Ocilib requires Oracle OCI shared library (oci.dll on windows) that is provided by regular or instant oracle clients.

Comment: I have downloaded oracle instant client and added the folder to my path. and there is a file by the name of (oci.dll) in the folder but the problem is still there.

Comment: Is that Instant-client a 32-bit version?